# Is Code Sourcery G++ Lite still a viable project?

Tags: arm, compiler, gcc

When I tried to download a newer version of Code Sourcery G++ Lite for ARM, 
I noticed that I was redirected to another company and it is really hard to find anything on that site about Sourcery G++ Lite for ARM.

Does anybody know the status on the Sourcery G++ Lite for ARM project?
Is it still alive, does people still work with it? Will it be available in the future?

---

Update: They seem to have renamed the project into **[Sourcery CodeBench Lite](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/lite-edition)**, so maybe the question is not relevant?

---

Update: Mentor Graphics is closing the project, it is no longer a viable alternative.

---

Notes: The current viable place to get gcc for ARM seems to be from Linaro

- https://www.linaro.org/about/
- https://www.linaro.org/downloads/
- https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded

Comment: There is still a list with releases: http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/subscription3053 But I can't find any link to that page from their main page...

Comment: Clicking "Download the current release" (under the "ARM Processors" section) on this page: http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/lite-edition then "EABI -> All versions" takes you there.

Comment: @Johan - Regardless of the name, it's no longer at codesourcery.com, where it's been forever.  It seems like a fine question.

Comment: there is an older package of it chk it http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/package5383/public/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-2009q3-67-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that Sourcery CodeBench Lite for ARM is no longer available.

Mentor Graphics appears to produce a Lite toolchain for other processors, but not for ARM.  They now direct you to obtain a trial of their commercial toolchain for the ARM processors.

**Update 27 January 2015**: the downloads are not available from these links anymore

<strike>The last Sourcery CodeBench Lite releases for ARM that I can find still available for download from Mentor Graphics are:</strike>

- [Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.11-24 for ARM EABI (Bare metal)](https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/release2635)
- [Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.11-33 for ARM GNU/Linux](https://sourcery.mentor.com/GNUToolchain/release2642)

These contain GCC 4.8.1.

They were available as of 18 Nov 2014. No telling how long that will remain true.

Comment: So the new answer NO... :(

Comment: This summary overlooks the critical difference between *sources* vs *executable builds* and the lite edition vs. the compiler itself.  If Mentor is still shipping a GCC derivative in their paid product for ARM, then they have an obligation to provide the complete corresponding sources thereof *without redistribution restrictions* While they may have stopped providing a read-to-go download, that doesn't mean you aren't able to create your own build to use.  Likely there is (or will be) some other source of a ready-to-go build.

Comment: This summary was simply providing information about the current state of Sourcery CodeBench Lite for ARM. My own search for an updated ARM Lite toolchain led me to this question, so I thought I'd share what I had found. I wasn't intending to delve into alternatives or building your own toolchain from source.

Comment: The source *is* the toolchain.  Prebuilt binaries are just a convenience.

Comment: @ChrisStratton regarding your note: "then they have an obligation to provide the complete corresponding sources thereof without redistribution restrictions" This applies to those they've distributed binaries to, so to get these sources one either needs to sign up for a trial or pay for the full package.

Comment: No James, it is only restricted to those they've distributed binaries to *if they provide the source with those binaries*.  If they do not, then they have to provide the source to third parties, including those they never distributed binaries to.

Comment: "Page Not Found"

Comment: @endolith: it looks like the links are working again.

Comment: The links in this answer say "Page Not Found"

Comment: @endolith: strange - the links still work from my home, but not from my work. Maybe something about browser cache or cookies or ???.  I've put the strikeout back. I'm not sure if I should delete the answer since I think some history about this might be helpful to people who are looking for the packages due to tutorials that refer to them.

Comment: Is there somewhere else these files are available?

Comment: @endolith: not that I'm aware of. Send an email to me (see my profile) - as I said I can still get access from home so I might be able to help you out.

Comment: Links: [arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi.exe](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi.exe), [arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi.bin](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi.bin), [arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi.src.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi.src.tar.bz2) and [arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2](https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2013.11-24-arm-none-eabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2)

Answer (score 23):

"Another Company" is the EDA giant Mentor Graphics. Whether they plan to embrace, extend, and extinguish the excellent G++ Lite toolchain or not, I do not know.  I *do* know that they're in business to sell Really Expensive Software.  Like other companies, they sell a front-end for Code Sourcery G++ Lite, and it's in their best interests to hide it as best as possible.  codesourcery.com didn't do as good a job hiding it.  Mentor Graphics hid it pretty well, which makes me skeptical of [this press release](http://www.mentor.com/company/news/codesourcery-open-source-acquisition) about their "commitment to the future of open source for embedded development."

However, they do a decent job of getting you to the commercial version, which, by the blessed GPL, contains links to the source.  I got to it by following the menu set [Products -> Embedded Software -> Sourcery Tools -> Sourcery CodeBench](http://www.mentor.com/embedded-software/sourcery-tools/sourcery-codebench/) and scrolling to the very bottom to find the personal, academic, and lite versions:

[image]

Those links direct you to the mysteriously difficult-to-navitage pages https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/subscription?@template=lite.
<sub><sup>The subscription breadcrumb in the URL and repeated suggestions to log in are for paid support and trials of the IDE.  Just ignore them.</sup></sub>

From that page, you'll see something like the following, with a link to the EABI version (An acronym for the [ARM Extended Application Binary Interface](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html), use this if you want to program bare-metal apps) as well as versions which link against the libraries that will be installed with other operating systems.

[image]

Clicking on the EABI "All versions" link from this page brings you to https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/subscription3053, the site you linked in your comment.

You're correct, there are no backwards links.  Use your browser history to navigate.

Slightly OT: I've used the Code Sourcery paid tools (they came free with a TI DSP DSK).  The debugging utilities would be handy for a beginner, but the rest of the tool set (the editor, the project builder, the GUI compiler configurator) was a pain.  I ended up using an external text editor, and just using the app for compiling and debugging.  I *certainly* don't think it was worth $2800.  You're taking the right route with the Lite edition.

Comment: It seems to be removed now.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, CodeSourcery is very much a viable company. I work closely with the CodeSourcery team (now at Mentor Graphics) on product strategy. The CodeSourcery Lite toolchains have been renamed Sourcery CodeBench Lite as you've noticed. Most of them were recently updated to gcc 4.6 this month. We've also expanded devices support as well. Full source code to the Lite releases is available as it always has been.

December 2012 update: New releases for Sourcery CodeBench Lite are out including updates to GCC 4.7.2, binutils 2.23, eglibc 2.16, and GDB 7.4.50.

Answer (score 2):

While they don't have any links on the site, the old download links still seem to work.

https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu.tar.bz2

https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi.src.tar.bz2

https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi.bin

https://sourcery.mentor.com/public/gnu_toolchain/arm-none-eabi/arm-2011.03-42-arm-none-eabi.exe

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure Mentor Graphics will make CodeSourcery to be close-source and you have to paid for any single line that you use. You can download from the link that Kelvin said. However there will be no more FREE for any further versions. Here is what I found [image]

Comment: gcc is using the GPL license so they are not allowed to close source it.